# Button to refresh combobox. "An item with the same key has already been added"

Tags: c#

I have a method which returns a list of objects from database. I use Dictionary to connect ID, with concated strings. I want FillComboBox method to refresh combobox after a click. Here is the FillComboBox code:

```
private void FillComboBox()
    {
        List<Shift> shifts = null;
        shifts = ShiftMenager.GetAllAsString();
        if (shifts.Count != 0)
        {
            Dictionary<int, string> shiftsDict = null;
            shiftsDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();
            shiftsDict.Clear();

            foreach (Shift sh in shifts)
            {
                shiftsDict.Add(sh.id, sh.startDate.ToShortDateString() +
                " (" + sh.startDate.ToShortTimeString() + " - " +
                sh.endDate.ToShortTimeString() + ") - " + sh.employee);
            }

            shiftComboBox.DisplayMember = "Value";
            shiftComboBox.ValueMember = "Key";
            shiftComboBox.DataSource = new BindingSource(shiftsDict, null);
        }
        else
        {
            shiftComboBox.Enabled = false;
        }
    }
```

I placed first FillComboBox() in

```
private void ShiftForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillComboBox();
    }
```

And second in button click event:

```
private void RefreshButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FillComboBox();
    }
```

When form loads everythings works fine but when I click a button I get a message "An item with the same key has already been added.". I can't find a way around it really, tried to clear dictionary before filling it, assign null first.
What is wrong? Thanks.

Comment: The code where you set the variable "shiftsDict" to null, and then clear it does nothing.  Just initialize it.  Dictionary<int, string> shiftsDict = new Dictionary<int, string>();

Comment: You can use 'shiftsDict[sh.id] = sh.startDate.ToShortDateString() +
                " (" + sh.startDate.ToShortTimeString() + " - " +
                sh.endDate.ToShortTimeString() + ") - " + sh.employee);' to add data to the Dictionary if you don't care about overwriting duplicates. This method won't complain about overwriting entries in the dictionary. It will automatically create / overwrite the entry in the Dictionary

Comment: You can debug this by enabling break on exception: 'Debug -> Exceptions: Enable 'Common Language Runtime Exceptions' -> enable 'Thrown'.

Comment: Could be that your shift manager is not clearing down an internal list when you call `GetAllAsString()` causing the dictionary to choke on a dupe ID the second time round

Comment: That was the problem. I never really thought that it can be a problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to debug your problem:

```
foreach (Shift sh in shifts)
{
  if (shiftsDict.ContainsKey(sh.id))
  {
    // code to log breakpoint on it to debug
  }
  else
  {
    shiftsDict.Add(sh.id, sh.startDate.ToShortDateString() +
      " (" + sh.startDate.ToShortTimeString() + " - " +
      sh.endDate.ToShortTimeString() + ") - " + sh.employee);
  }
}
```

Comment: I placed a message box in place of comment. And what I get when I click the button the first time is: 26,25,24,23,22,21 which is Ok. But when I click it the second time I get 26,25,24,23,22,21,26,25,24,23,22,21 which is really wierd because I don't really know where the duplication takes place.

Comment: @user2832281 - post the code for `ShiftMenager.GetAllAsString()` that is where the bug is then.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not coming from Combobox. Source of the error is the dictionary you're using. I'm sure your code is trying to add a duplicate entry with same already added key.

Just make sure the collection `shifts = ShiftMenager.GetAllAsString()` doesn't have any duplicate entry.